# PHP Check Url and detect empty parameters parts

Tags: php, parameters

I Have Url structure for multi language system like this:

for default language ie: `en`

`localhost/cms`

And Another Language Like:

`localhost/cms/fr`

`localhost/cms/de`

`localhost/cms/es`

Now I have this function for detect empty url language short name parts and set to default language:

```
function urlss(){

    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $languages = ['en', 'fr', 'es', 'de'];

    // this is my default language
    $defaultLang = 'en';

    // $currentLang is the language I'll use to show the contents
    $currentLang = $defaultLang;

    $uri = ltrim(rawurldecode($uri), '/');
    $parts = explode('/', $uri);

    if( ! empty($parts) && in_array(strtolower($parts[0]), $languages)) {
        $currentLang = array_shift($parts);
    }

    $routableUri = implode('/', $parts);

return $routableUri;

}
```

Check in Url: `localhost/cms/` and Output Is: `cms/` and not work true.

In action I need to check My url, if not detect language short name ie: `en` default language = `en` and then put in `session` or `cookie` But if detect language short name ie: `fr` `es` `de` set `session` or `cookie` to this language.

How do can I fix my problem and check my url for language short name?!

Comment: Are you sure you want to write your own routing system? Why not use an existing one that can handle all that parsing stuff for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this problem using a regular expression.

```
// Prepare request URI, available languages and default language
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$languages = ['en', 'fr', 'es', 'de'];
$default = 'en';

// Build regular expression and attempt to match language in URL
preg_match('/^\/cms\/(' . implode('|', $languages) . ')\//', $url, $match);

// Set language to match or default to English
$language = $match[1] ?? $default;

// Remove default language from URL
$url = preg_replace("/\/{$default}/", '', $url);
```

Comment: all output is `en`. ie: check `localhost/cms/fr` output is : `en`. `localhost/cms` ouput is: `en` `localhost/cms/de` output is 'en' and more .....

Comment: Your example URLs show the language portion being the first part of the request URI - `example.com/de`, `example.com/fr`? Please update your question to show representative examples.

Comment: Ok. You Right. I edit My Q. Actually i check in my `localhost url` and then in real `url`.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the URL always starting with `/cms/`. If this isn't correct, please update your question again.

Comment: thanks worked now. but for route url i need to print full structure like this: for another lang `cms/fr/article/slug/...` and for default lang `cms/article/slug/...`.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand what you’re asking. Can you explain further?

Comment: sorry for delay. my code output print routable url like this : for all language `cms/en/users/slug/....` Or `cms/de/users/slug/...` Now for default language i need to remove defualt language from url and print like this: (for default language remove language short code)`cms/users/slug/....` and for another language show language short code `cms/de/users/....`.

Comment: @NewCod3r, I've added another line to remove the default language (`en`) from the URL when it exists.

Comment: I need to add `en` to ouput if not detect/exsits in url like this :`localhost/cms/usres` output is : `cms/en/users`

Comment: I add New Question please check/see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50965587/php-check-url-and-print-default-parameters

Comment: Why do you need to do that if you’re already setting a default language when it doesn’t appear in the URL?

Comment: in my route class I need to add language to prefix for app folder structure and need to this : `cms/en/users/` Or `cms/fr/users/` Or `cms/de/users/` But For Better Url Method(GoogleSeo/Multi language user friendly url and ...) In need to remove default language from url like this: `localhost/cms/users`.

Answer (score 0):

The regex approach is better one another way is you can take an intersection of `$languages` array with URL `$parts`.

```
function urlss(){

    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $languages = ['en', 'fr', 'es', 'de'];

    // this is my default language
    $defaultLang = 'en';

    // $currentLang is the language I'll use to show the contents
    $currentLang = $defaultLang;

    $uri = ltrim(rawurldecode($uri), '/');
    // uri might have many / characters
    $parts = explode('/', $uri);

    if( ! empty($parts)) {
        $result = array_uintersect($languages , $parts, "strcasecmp");
        if(!empty($result)){ 
           $currentLang = $result[0];
           $parts = array_diff($parts, [ $result[0] ]);
        }
    }

    $routableUri = implode('/', $parts);

    return $routableUri;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$languages = ['en', 'fr', 'es', 'de'];
$defaultLang = 'en';

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = rtrim($url, '/');//remove last slash if available
$parsed_arr = parse_url($url);//not necessary if you don't want to validate url 
$segments = explode("/", $parsed_arr['path']);//split parsed url into segments
$language = end($segments); //take the last one

if(in_array($language,$languages))
    $currentLang = $language;
else
    $currentLang = $defaultLang;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets have a try this code :

**Check This out [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)**

**Rest you can easily change as per your need but i have corrected the logic of function**

```
<?php
   $currentUrls= array('cms/es','cms/en','cms/de','cms/fr','cms/');
   echo 'Before::<br >';
   foreach($currentUrls as $currentUrl){
      echo ($currentUrl);
     echo '<hr/>';
   }

function urlss($currentUrl){
    $uri =$currentUrl;
    $languages = ['en', 'fr', 'es', 'de'];
    // this is my default language
   $defaultLang = 'en';
   // $currentLang is the language I'll use to show the contents
   $currentLang = $defaultLang;
   $uri = ltrim(rawurldecode($uri), '/');       
   list($cms,$url_language) = explode('/', $uri);     

  //if langugage is in array then 
  if( in_array( strtolower($url_language), $languages)){
      $currentLang = $url_language;      
  }else { 
      $currentLang = $defaultLang;      
  }

  $newUrl = array($cms,$currentLang);
  $routableUri = implode('/', $newUrl);
  return $routableUri;
 }

 echo '<br ><br >After::<br >';
 foreach($currentUrls as $currentUrl){
    echo urlss($currentUrl);
    echo '<hr/>';
 }
```

?>

[image]