# PHP Check Url and print default parameters

Tags: php

I Have Url structure for multi language system like this:

for default language ie: `en` (not show/detect short language in url)

`localhost/cms`

`localhost/cms/article/slug/etc...`

And Another Language Like:

`localhost/cms/fr`

`localhost/cms/fr/article/slug/etc...`

My Idea:

1. define a list of available languages for My app,
2. define a default language I use when,
    a. there is no language provided (`localhost/cms/users`),
    b. the provided language is unknown (`localhost/cms/fr/users`).
3. in my code, get the current Language (ex: `en`) and the routableURI,
   a URI without any language in it (ex: cms/users)

I have This code:

```
function urlss(){

    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $languages = ['en', 'fr', 'es', 'de'];

    // this is my default language
    $defaultLang = 'en';

    // $currentLang is the language I'll use to show the contents
    $currentLang = $defaultLang;

    $uri = ltrim(rawurldecode($uri), '/');
    $parts = explode('/', $uri);

    if( ! empty($parts) && in_array(strtolower($parts[0]), $languages)) {
        $currentLang = array_shift($parts);
    }

    $routableUri = implode('/', $parts);

return $routableUri;

}
```

My code output default language: *(false Output)and not worked*

check: `localhost/cms/` Or `localhost/cms/users/`

Output is: `cms/` Or `cms/users/`

Output for another language: *(true Output)worked true*

check: `localhost/cms/fr/` Output is `cms/fr/` Or `localhost/cms/fr/users/`Output is : `cms/fr/users/`

How do can i print my default language, without add/detect short language name in url like this?!

Check: `localhost/cms` Output Is:`cms/en` Or Check `localhost/cms/users/` Output Is: `cms/en/users/`.

Comment: maybe storing them in Cookie?

Comment: @BARNI: Belike, But In this Case I add To Route Class for routing url.